# Update SQLITE database from server in background swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, ios7

I am developing an app in which I am using SQLite database.what I am trying to implement is

1. Load data from server and add these data to local database.
2. Show data to user from local database not directly from server, so that if there is no internet connection user can see some old data.

This will be static data always but it will be huge amount of data.
Now I want to update this data for a particular time duration say in every 24 hours but this I want to do in background. This is about loading data but some data will be for uploading this will be small amount of data.
I have seen apple IOS-7 release features(Background fetch and Background Transfer Service),but what I understood is we can only download files from server by using this,I read this from this answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23047412/background-fetch-and-background-transfers-in-ios-to-download-data-json-on-bakc)

but I have to deal with JSON. I have searched a lot how should I perform this but not getting any right solution.
I have this tutorial for background tasks

[Background Transfer Service](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-7-sdk-background-transfer-service--mobile-20595)

there are many more tutorials but I am not getting how I can implement it in my case.

if I am not clear with my question please let me know I will provide more details.

Thanks for all help.

one more point I want to tell, database structure is almost same as server database.

Comment: Do you really need all the data? And in the background can be when the user is using the app (it needs to be really)?

Comment: yes I need to update all data from server in a particular time duration and it should be done when user is not using the app

Comment: Well, you can't always have what you want... Background downloading could be done by file, but if you always download a massive file the system will stop scheduling your task, and it gets to decide when to do it anyway.

Comment: mean I can not call a web service in background and do some parsing and add parsed data to sqlite?

Comment: Some yes, by a couple of different methods, but not for 'huge amount of data'

Comment: Users may want to fo it at specific times, and only over wifi, you don't know what their situation will be at arbitrary times

Comment: so how should I achieve this task?I should not choose background mode?Should i perform all this when user launch app and block screen till data is up to date?

Comment: I'd do it when the user opens the app, if the network connection is good enough, but not block the UI

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion a better solution would be if you save the time of the latest update of the database. Whenever the user opens your app (this is the only time he wants to see new information) and your saved timestamp is at least 24hours ago, you should update the data in your database.